# Validate manifest.mainClass in maven-jar-plugin

Tags: java, maven, build-automation, maven-jar-plugin

Is there a way to validate (even using another plugin) that the `mainClass` specified for the `maven-jar-plugin` is a valid class, and even better that it has a `public static void main(String[] argv)` method?

It is common that after refactoring, this is the one thing that gets missed and I would like to avoid this and check at the `verify` lifecycle stage.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin) and its [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal to execute the following command:

```
java -jar target\project.jar
```

Which would indeed execute it according to the manifest file (hence executing the configured main method) or fail.

You could thus add to the `verify` phase the following (sample) configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.sample.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-main</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-jar</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            <argument>sanityCheck</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the snippet above we are:

- Configuring the `maven-jar-plugin` to configure the main class in its manifest (a sample `com.sample.Main` in this case)
- Configure the `exec-maven-plugin` to execute the `java` command above on the final artifact (note the usage of maven properties to avoid hard-coded artifact names and path, recommended)
- As a suggestion, also pass to this execution a further argument which your main method should foresee as sanity check, that is, execute it for a *dry-run* like (just print an information to the console or simply return immediately)
- The execution will run successfully if the information of the manifest are correct, fail otherwise (and as such your build).

---

Simply renaming the `main` method to `main2` would break the build with the following message:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ simple ---   
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Development\workspace-mars\simple\target\simple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar   
[INFO]   
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (check-main) @ simple ---   
Error: Main method not found in class com.sample.Main, please define the main method as:   
   public static void main(String[] args)   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the message above is pretty much what you were looking for:

> Error: Main method not found in class com.sample.Main, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)